# javascript Ninja book with callback example

Tags: javascript

So reading and making progress on this excellent book Javascript Ninja. Question on below code though,I cannot understand the life of me why cb.call was used and what's more why context which is seemingly empty, is being passed. I think it could have just done cb(this[i],i,this) since 'this' is not being used. Am I missing a huge point here? Please help. thank you.

```
<ul id="results"></ul>
<script>
  function assert(val,desc){
     var li = document.createElement("li");
 li.className = val ? "pass" : "fail"; 
 li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(desc));
 document.getElementById("results").appendChild(li);

  }

  if ( !Array.prototype.forEach2) {
     Array.prototype.forEach2 = function(cb,context){
     for ( var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
         cb.call(context ||null, this[i], i, this);
     }
 }; 
  }

  ["a,","b","c"].forEach2(function(value,index,array){
     assert(value,"Is in position " + index + " out of " + (array.length - 1));           
  });

  assert(true,"this will be green");
  assert(false,"this is RED");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the specific example for `forEach2` listed you are right, context (`this`) is not being used so you could just do a regular function call in the implementation.  If you didn't ever care about having a specific value of `this` in your callback function then you could stop here and just use the regular function call.

However, implementing using `.call` and allowing a context to be passed gives you the option of passing a specific context value should you need it at some point but doesn't *require* that you pass it if you don't need it.  Meaning, you could do this:

```
var context = { 
    something: 'hello'
};

['a', 'b', 'c'].forEach2(function(value, index, array) {
    // this.something would be 'hello' in this function
}, context);
```